# How I can attach multiple image to facebook feed message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

Right now I use this method to add feed message:

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
                    $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
                        'link' => $this->cafe->getUrlForPost(),
                        'name' => $this->cafe->getTextForPost(),
                        'picture' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->getImageForPost()
                    )
                ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

Is there any way to add a multiple image in **picture** field? Or maybe do you have a workaround for this?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now you can´t add more than one image in one API call. You can only do multiple calls and you can use Batch Requests for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: Thank you for answer. But if I call multiple request - I get multiple post.
I want add into one message several picture (like  'picture' =>$picture1, $picture2, $picture3 )

Comment: In twitter I can make this: 

$Twitter->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => 'Hello world.', 'media_ids' => 38382028323,3483923948); 

And with this message will be show 2 picture.

Comment: i know, batch requests are only there to make it faster. you can´t create it in one message with the api, at least not right now.